# Excel look-up column data

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I have two data tabs for survey responses - the first shows the full set of exepcted responses an which office they are from

```
HMIP  LDU
1     Leeds
2     Leeds
3     Leeds
4     Leeds
5     Wakefield
```

The second those that have actually responded and I need to get their office location next to the ID:

```
HMIPID  WYLDU
1   
2   
3   
5
```

I have hundreds and will be doing this a lot so any help appreciated!

Comment: @smirkingman In order to help the entire community of Superuser, when posting a comment, please explain yourself. When giving an answer, post it in the "Answer" area below and please give some detail to help anyone who reads it. Just posting a single word does not necessarily help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how VLookup should be used in your case:

[image]

Comment: Thank smirkingman - worked a treat and now I'll go and learn more about Excel formulae!

Comment: You're welcome. It's considered polite to accept the best answer with the tick sign on the left. It'll help your reputation too >:-)